# Does anyone remember an early 90s side-scroller with a player-controlled ED-209-like robot?

Tags: ibm-pc, identify-this-game

I remember playing a side-scroller at a Babbage's at the mall (on probably a sweet Compaq; I don't think it was on a C64, an Amiga, an Apple, or anything more exotic), probably around 1993, where the player controlled a robot that was modeled on the ED-209 from Robocop.

I also seem to remember the sprite size for the character being memorably small relative to the size of the screen, perhaps to show more of the surroundings. The environment was futuristic metal caves or factories or something.

Does anyone remember this, or am I imagining things?

Comment: I think the only game featuring a licensed ED-209 is [RoboCop versus the Terminator](https://www.mobygames.com/game/robocop-versus-the-terminator_), but that’s a console game, and you don’t control the ED-209.

Comment: This was ED-209-inspired, but definitely not a Robocop universe game.

Comment: The first game that immediately comes to mind is Walker on the Amiga. Time and theme match, but it wasn't released on the PC. It was side-scrolling and mouse controlled.
https://www.mobygames.com/game/amiga/walker

Comment: Hmm, I don't think it was Walker based on the screengrabs.

Comment: Might be generous to call it retro, but XEvil had a "walker" class that sort of fits the description...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Upgraded from a mere comment, my suggestion is the Psygnosis title The Killing Game Show (Amiga/ST), also released as Fatal Rewind (Sega Mega Drive/Genesis):

[image]
[image]

It was released in 1990 for the computers and 1991 for the Sega; another notable element of the game besides the robot and metallic corridors is the rising water level that acts like a level timer. A full review of the Sega version, including more detailed gameplay details, can be found [here](http://www.sega-16.com/2006/09/fatal-rewind/).

Answer (score 4):

I suspect this is [Robozone](https://www.mobygames.com/game/robozone). It was released in 1991 on a number of platforms, including DOS PCs, and features a robot which looks similar to the ED-209:

[image: Robot destroying an enemy]

There’s a [longplay of the Amiga version](https://archive.org/details/Amiga_500_Longplay_062_Robozone) on archive.org; skip ahead to 5:30 to see the gameplay.

Answer (score 0):

I found it at last. This is "Metal Mech: Man & Machine" for NES

Comment: Mind to add some information/picture/link to make it worthwhile - and more important why you think it'll be the right answer?